# Homology of Torus via Excision

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to compute the homology of the torus via excision.

My attempt was to consider $A$ a subspace of the torus $\Bbb{T}^2$ homeomorphic to a disk $D^2$ and $U$ a smaller (now open) disk contained in $A$, in such a way that it satisfies the conditions of the excision theorem, i.e., $\bar{U}\subset int(A)$. Then, we have, from excision
$$ H_n(\Bbb{T}^2, A) \cong H_n(\Bbb{T}^2 - U, A-U). $$

But the problem is that $\Bbb{T}^2 -U$ have the homotopy type as $S^1\vee S^1$ and $A-U$ the homotopy type of $S^1$, which would give us that the right hand side of the above isomorphism is actually $H_n(S^1\vee S^1, S^1)$, which is isomorphic to $H_n(S^1)$. This obviously should not happen, for the homology group of $\Bbb{T}^2$ is not isomorphic to the homology of $S^1$, and $H_n(\Bbb{T}^2, A)\cong\tilde{H}(\Bbb{T}^2)$.

Thus there must be something wrong with my argument, but I am not able to identify what is it.

Comment: You have $H_n(\mathbb{T}^2,A) = H_n(\mathbb{T}\setminus A)$ (or at least you can prove it) beware the injection $S^1 \to S^1 \vee S^1$ is not the same as the injection $A\setminus U \to \mathbb{T}^2 \setminus U$

Comment: More specifically, the map $A\setminus U \to \mathbb{T}^2 \setminus U$ induces the zero map on $H_1$.